# Custom Field select list is truncated

Tags: custom-field, pages, wp-admin

The site I'm working on has many custom fields being used in it's pages.  For some reason though, the list of custom fields that you can pick from the dropdown only displays the first 30 field names.

If I want to use an existing custom field that isn't, alphabetically, in the first 30, I have to manually type it in each time.

Any idea why?

Comment: Using WordPress 3.8 btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-field-limit) there is a WordPress limit of 30 for the number of custom fields that are available by default. But you can change the behavior as shown with the hook `postmeta_form_limit` in the below example.

```
add_filter( 'postmeta_form_limit' , 'customfield_limit_increase' );
function customfield_limit_increase( $limit ) {
    $limit = 100;
    return $limit;
}
```